# Cannot save after deleting entity in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I want to delete all records with some lineId to save another records with the same lineId(as refresh) but after deleting I can't save anything. There isn't any error, but I don't have my record in database.

When I don't have ma deleting code everything saves correctly.

```
public void deleteAndSaveEntities(List<Entity> entities, Long lineId){
    deleteEntities(lineId);
    saveEntities(entities);
}

private void deleteEntities(Long lineId) {
    List<Entity> entitiesToDelete = entityRepository.findAllByLineId(lineId);
    entityRepository.deleteAll(entitiesToDelete); 
}

private void saveEntities(List<Entity> entities) {
    entityRepository.saveAll(entities);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you update the entities instead? I can imagine 2 reasons for the behavior you're experiencing: 1) Hibernate marks the entities as deleted first and interprets the `save()` as an update since the entities are still in the first level cache. The update then doesn't update anything because the rows have been deleted already. 2) Hibernate reorders the statements for performance reasons and executes the deletes last. I assume option 1 is more likely but to get some more insight, try to log the SQL statements that Hibernate executes - you should see what happens in which order.

Comment: This is connected with some diagram calibration, when user change the calibration I need new points connected with the line -> not always the same ammount of the points in database and what's more often totally another points, because they are calculated after every calibration. So this was the best option for me. Maybe there is the way to clear cache/start some new session before saving?

Comment: Did you try to call `entityRepository.flush()` after delete? Of course by doing this, it will slow down the performance a little :)

Comment: If so, you could do the following: 1) load the existing points, 2) update the points that are present in the "new" collection, 3) delete any existing points not present in the "new" collection, 4) add new points that are not present in the "existing" collection. What's new and existing depends on how you defined your ids but it could be as simple as a size difference: any index not present in "existing" is new ("new" is larger than "existing"), any index not present in "new" gets deleted ("new" is smaller than "existing").

Answer (score 0):

Actually you want to update the entries that has the `lineId`. Try it as:

1. First fetch by find..().
2. Make related changes on that entries
3. Then save them.

Comment: But it is connected with some diagram calibration, when user change the calibration I need new points connected with the line -> not always the same ammount of the points in database, because they are calculated after every calibration. So this was the best option for me

Answer (score 0):

As thomas mentioned, hibernate reorders the queries within the transaction for performance reasons and executes the delete after the update.

I would commit the transaction between these two operations.
Add a @Transactional over deleteEntities and saveEntities.
But be aware that @Transactional does not work when invoked with in the same object.
You must inject the Service into itself and then call the methods on the self reference